# How to add some common include in thousands of jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I gotta situation where my project is up & running from many years. 
Now to enhance it's security I'm planning to include some code (Using a common javascript & jsp file) in **every** jsp file. 
To overcome this **manual work**, is there any way out where I can configure my web application (In web.xml or somewhere else) and my file includes goes with every page my container dispatch.
Sample Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myCommonCode.js"></script>
<%@include file="myHelperFile.jsp" %>
```

Comment: Should not be too hard to make the necessary changes in the source files with a little shell script. On *NIX I would use a combination of `find` and `sed` to achieve that.

Comment: Did you ever include other own jsp file? like `<%@include file="header.jsp" %>`, if so, you just add your code in header.jsp. If not you have to add a line like that. You can use shell to modify files or use replace function in IDE. Find some markable code and add your line

Comment: @Henry suggests a shell script, but this should also be possible to do directly in the IDE. Search and replace? Most IDE:s, such as IntelliJ IDEA, supports search and replace with regexp.

Comment: @Bejond No there is not any common jsp file which I can utilize.

Comment: Henry & Magnilex, I know that using some script or by finding and adding content I can do. But what I'm expecting is that while dispatching the jsp my container handle such thing. And that I can further enhance and control as well.